# Shrinking a database...should I

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a database which is around 20GB in size but actually free space is around 17GB.  This has happened because I have moved out quite a few audit tables that were large in size to another database altogether.

I mistakenly tried to perform a shrink database whilst in business hours but didn't realise the time it would take it to complete this so managed to stop it.

I've now done some research on this and I've read articles where shrinking a database shouldnt be done because it can cause "massive" index fragmentation.  I'm no SQL guru but this does ring alarm bells.

People have suggested using a shrink with truncate only.

Are there any sql experts out there that can help me out with the right thing to do here??

Comment: Probably better to ask on dba.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @DavidG - thank you!

Comment: @JasonClark I'm assuming the overisize was due to my large audit tables that were in the db to begin with - which I've now removed as stated in my post..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shrinking a database after you remove a large amount of data in a one-time operation is proper.  You want to leave plenty of free space, as re-growing can be expensive.  And you want to rebuild indexes after shrinking, to remove the fragmentation.

But here the database is only 20GB, so shrinking it won't really solve any problems.  If you wanted to shrink it to 6GB or so, that would be fine.  But I would just leave it at 20GB.